# jQuery click evt is cancelling out validation script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still learning jQuery and JS. This code allows the div `.causeBox.step2` to toggle inputs from unchecked to checked:

```
  var extendcheck = function(evt) { 
  if (evt.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
       var $checkbox = $(":checkbox", this);
       $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
       evt.stopPropagation();
       return false;
  }
  };
  $('.causeBox.step2').click(extendcheck);
```

However, when I add that code, it breaks the form validation that someone else I'm working with wrote:

```
function checkAll() {
    if($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length >= 1) {
      $("input:submit:not([class='ready'])").removeAttr("disabled");
      $("input:submit:not([class='ready'])").addClass("ready");
    } else {
      $("input:submit").removeClass("ready");
      $("input:submit:not([class='ready'])").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  }
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(e) {
    checkAll();
  }); 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    checkAll();
  });
```

Can someone point me in the direction of what is causing these two to conflict (no errors in the console), so that I can modify the code that I've added to work without breaking the existing `checkAll()` function?

UPDATE: Pertinent HTML added. I've only included one of the full `.causeBox.step2` divs to cut length.

```
<form class="edit_guest_user" id="edit_guest_user_224" action="/guest_users/224" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="+rNXqFJC7Iq+EmDLlMuYfUVAlYro3NZ8qIlg3+jBQOfMR8V81pMMgJpgG9hWb8wyhVcVHE07tWq7BgDLhjcHrg==">

        <div class="hero onboarding">
          <h1>test, what are you passionate about?</h1>
          <p>You can select as many Cause Portfolios as you like.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="causeContainer">
            <div class="causeBox step2">
              <input type="checkbox" name="guest_user[cause_ids][]" id="344668625" value="344668625">
              <span class="newCheck"></span>
              <label for="344668625" class="newCheck"></label>
              <div class="causeInterior">
                <img src="/assets/causes/inequality_icon-b8c54c95ed86c24b471f00c30d2ac98f23a9ede8dfac1f7ea5c9614f770addae.png" alt="Inequality icon">
                <h2><label for="344668625">Inequality</label></h2>
                <div class="button passion-detail">
                  <a id="modal-opener" href="#modal-344668625" rel="modal:open">Learn More</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div id="modal-344668625" class="modal">

              <div class="modal-header long">
                <h2>Partner Charities in This Portfolio</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-content">

                  <div class="charity-container">

                    <img class="charityLogo" src="/Youthlinc/Youthlinc+TRANS.png" alt="Youthlinc+trans">

                    <div class="charity-info">
                      <h2>Youthlinc</h2>
                      <p>Creating lifetime humanitarians since 1999.</p>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                <div class="button more">
                  <a href="#close-modal" rel="modal:close">Ok</a>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="next_step" id="next_step" value="salary">

        <div>
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="" data-disable-with="" class="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: Please post all the relevant code (HTML) so we can replicate your issue. I can say that you shouldn't be calling `checkAll` in `document.ready` and you don't need to wrap `checkAll()` inside of an anonymous function in the `change` event - just reference `checkAll` directly (no parenthesis when you do that).

Comment: `evt` and `e` aren't the issue. They are local parameters that don't affect other functions and you aren't doing anything with `e` in the first place.

Comment: Remove `evt.stopPropagation()` and `return false;` from your code. `div` element doesn't have default behavior on `click` event so `return false;` is redundant. `stopPropagation` cancels *someone*'s code.

Comment: Also, `$checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));` isn't going to do what you want because the value of the `checked` attribute when a checkbox is checked is `checked`. There is no opposite keyword of `checked` that will make a checkbox not checked. It's a boolean attribute. You should work with the **property** instead:  `$checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev That does resolve the issue but it also makes just the `label` element within the div clickable to toggle the checkbox rather than the whole div (`div.causeBox.step2`). I'm not familiar enough with what I'm doing here yet to know why that would have that effect.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks, Scott. Relevant HTML has been added to the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Try `$('.causeBox.step2 [type=checkbox]').click(extendcheck);`

Comment: You still haven't added all the relevant HTML so that we can reproduce your issue. Where's the `form` and the `submit`?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev That also resolves the conflict with the validation code, but similarly makes just the `label` element clickable to toggle the checkbox rather than the whole div. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Amended again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, if you re-organize it and remove the incorrect function calls.

You shouldn't be calling `checkAll()` in `document.ready` because the user hasn't done anything at that point.

You shouldn't be wrapping a call to `checkAll()` in an anonymous function since that call doesn't pass any parameters.

The `return false` isn't breaking your code, but it's not doing anything for you.

Also, as I mentioned in the comments. You should use the `checked` ***property*** if you want to get its boolean opposite, rather than the `checked` ***attribute*** (which doesn't have a boolean value to get the opposite of).

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on("change", checkAll); 
$('.causeBox.step2').on("click", extendcheck);

function extendcheck(evt) { 
  if (evt.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
     var $checkbox = $(":checkbox", this);
     $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
     evt.stopPropagation(); 
  }
};

function checkAll() {
  if($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length >= 1) {
    $("input:submit:not([class='ready'])").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("input:submit:not([class='ready'])").addClass("ready");
  } else {
    $("input:submit").removeClass("ready");
    $("input:submit:not([class='ready'])").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}
```

```css
.ready {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="edit_guest_user" id="edit_guest_user_224" action="/guest_users/224" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="+rNXqFJC7Iq+EmDLlMuYfUVAlYro3NZ8qIlg3+jBQOfMR8V81pMMgJpgG9hWb8wyhVcVHE07tWq7BgDLhjcHrg==">

        <div class="hero onboarding">
          <h1>test, what are you passionate about?</h1>
          <p>You can select as many Cause Portfolios as you like.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="causeContainer">
            <div class="causeBox step2">
              <input type="checkbox" name="guest_user[cause_ids][]" id="344668625" value="344668625">
              <span class="newCheck"></span>
              <label for="344668625" class="newCheck"></label>
              <div class="causeInterior">
                <img src="/assets/causes/inequality_icon-b8c54c95ed86c24b471f00c30d2ac98f23a9ede8dfac1f7ea5c9614f770addae.png" alt="Inequality icon">
                <h2><label for="344668625">Inequality</label></h2>
                <div class="button passion-detail">
                  <a id="modal-opener" href="#modal-344668625" rel="modal:open">Learn More</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div id="modal-344668625" class="modal">

              <div class="modal-header long">
                <h2>Partner Charities in This Portfolio</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-content">

                  <div class="charity-container">

                    <img class="charityLogo" src="/Youthlinc/Youthlinc+TRANS.png" alt="Youthlinc+trans">

                    <div class="charity-info">
                      <h2>Youthlinc</h2>
                      <p>Creating lifetime humanitarians since 1999.</p>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                <div class="button more">
                  <a href="#close-modal" rel="modal:close">Ok</a>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="next_step" id="next_step" value="salary">

        <div>
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="" data-disable-with="" class="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>

    </form>
```